# Error : Call to a member function where() on int

Tags: laravel

I want to update data only in pivot table in Laravel 8. All columns are foreign keys. While run the following query, the data in pivot table has been updated but Laravel form give the following error.

**Error**:

```
Call to a member function where() on int
```

**Controller**:

```
DB::table("student_topic_examiner")->update([
                        "internal_id" => $internal->id,
                        "external_id" => $external->id])
                        ->where("roll_number", "=", $request->input('roll_number'));
```

Database pivot table is as [pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctPZZ.png).
Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `where()` after `update()`.

`update()` returns a integer (`1` if something was updated, `0` otherwise).

It means that you code translates to `(1)->where("roll_number", "=", $request->input('roll_number'))`.

If you only want to update the rows where this condition is true:

```php
->where("roll_number", "=", $request->input('roll_number'))
```

Then, call it **before** `update()`:

```php
DB::table("student_topic_examiner")
                   ->where("roll_number", "=", $request->input('roll_number'))
                   ->update([
                        "internal_id" => $internal->id,
                        "external_id" => $external->id]
                   );
```